# Get corp name from LDAP without having windows authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api, authorization, windows-authentication

I need to get the corporate name this is the basic thing. But my problem is i need to get them through WEB API. I have tried impersonate set to true in web config enabled Windows authentication also. I can get the details locally when i run postman, but the same when i try to access after deploying in server it shows the following things:

1) Corporate domain name returns empty
2) Access denied (when anonymous is set to disable mode)

I am confused whether this can be done without having a windows authentication prompt box. If yes have i missed something while configuring IIS? 
Thanks everyone in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way too late to answer this but SSO is what i need and i have come across Ping Identity.

So using SSO i can get the details of the user who are logged in.

[PingIdentity - SSO](https://www.pingidentity.com/en.html)